# Drawing curve with fixed length

Tags: android, ios, graphics, opengl-es, curve

actually I don't know how this calls, but:

I would like to implement such functionality: I'm drawing curve with cursor. And this line has to be e.g. 100 pixels length, no more.... When the length of this curve became greater than 100 px, the last (old) pixels have to be hidden (erased) .... I don't think that that creating array of this pixels is a good idea, so I need your advice, plz

Comment: What language/platform are you working in?

Comment: both android and iOS ... suppose to use OpenGL

Comment: updated the question tags... should help get the right eyeballs on the question.

Comment: ok ... if you think its needed ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because of OpenGLES does not support glBegin/End you have no option except for arrays. Since 100px are not too much to reallocate you may use a linked-list structure to store pixel data, then reconstruct Opengl buffers each time update occurs (input events).

Instead of linked-list, I can suggest using array by holding start and end indexes and let them cycle trough the array. But you need to be careful about fraction point. A pseudo code would be like this:

```
    public void addVertice(float x,float y){
    {
        if(curveLength<MAX_CURVE_SIZE)
        {
            ar[end][0]=x;
            ar[end][1]=y;
            end++;
            curveLength++;
        }
        else{
            ar[end][0]=x;
            ar[end][1]=y;
            end=1+(end+1)%(MAX_CURVE_SIZE-1);// cycle, but never left only one element in array
            start=1+(start+1)%(MAX_CURVE_SIZE-1);
            ar[MAX_CURVE_SIZE][0]=ar[1][0];
            ar[MAX_CURVE_SIZE][1]=ar[1][0];
            ar[0][0]=ar[MAX_CURVE_SIZE-1][0];
            ar[0][1]=ar[MAX_CURVE_SIZE-1][0];


        }
        updateBuffers();
    }
```

To draw the buffer you will need to handle two sitation; If `start` is less than `end`, then draw start to the end. If `start` is greater than `end`, you will need to draw `start` to `MAX_CURVE_LENGTH` and 0 to `end`. For both, you can use same indices buffer.